# Zone transfer failed "while receiving responses: invalid NS owner name (wildcard)" from Microsoft to bind 9.16

Tags: domain-name-system

I am using Bind 9.16 free BSD and trying to transfer zone data from the Microsoft DNS server but from the bind server I have the following logs,

{
transfer of 'xxxxx.xxx.xx/IN' from xx.xx.xx.xx#53: Transfer completed: 20 messages, 9091 records, 327278 bytes, 0.018 secs (18182111 bytes/sec) (serial 241231382)21/03/2022 14:21:15

transfer of 'xxxxx.xxx.xx/IN' from xx.xx.xx.xx#53: Transfer status: invalid NS owner name (wildcard) 21/03/2022 14:21:15

transfer of 'xxxxx.xxx.xx/IN' from xx.xx.xx.xx#53: failed while receiving responses: invalid NS owner name (wildcard)
}

How we can fix this issue since the zone transfer is failed without any disruption of the production environment on windows,

Comment: show us the zone file, i believe that you have a mismatch on the server name on the firat soa line

Comment: First off, is the error message accurate... Ie, is there a delegation with a wildcard owner name? If so, I guess investigate why that is and fix it

Comment: Did you check the box "Enable BIND secondaries" in the advanced settings?

Answer (score 2):

> invalid NS owner name (wildcard)

Means you have probably `* NS something` in your zonefile, which is not allowed.

You need to fix the content of your zone.

From RFC4592 §4.2:

```
As a result of these discussions, there is no definition given for
wildcard domain names owning an NS RRSet.  The semantics are left
undefined until there is a clear need to have a set defined, and
until there is a clear direction to proceed.  Operationally,
inclusion of wildcard NS RRSets in a zone is discouraged, but not
barred.
```

But that becomes in fact "barred" at least for `bind`, as it is easy to test:

```
$ cat example.com.zone
example.com. IN 1 SOA ns.example. noc.example. 1 7200 3600 1209600 3600
example.com. IN NS a.example.
example.com. IN NS b.example.

* NS a.example.

$ named-checkzone example.com example.com.zone
example.com.zone:2: using RFC1035 TTL semantics
dns_master_load: example.com.zone:8: *.example.com: invalid NS owner name (wildcard)
zone example.com/IN: loading from master file example.com.zone failed: invalid NS owner name (wildcard)
zone example.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```